# How can I set input value to the state in redux reducer file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, redux

This is my input

```
<input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    props.setInputVal(e.target.value);
                }}
            />
```

This is the action file

```
export const setInputVal = (val) => {
    return {
        type: SET_INPUT,
        payload: val
    };
};
```

This is the state I want to set input's value to in redux reducer

```
const initialState = {
    inputVal: ''
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_INPUT:
            return {
                inputVal: [ action.payload ]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

But I'm getting the an error so How can I properly set the input value when user types in to the inputVal state in redux reducer ?

Comment: "But I'm getting the an error" What error do you get? Which line causes it?

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Using Redux with React](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react). Pay close attention to the `mapStateToProps()` function and how it is used with the `connect()` higher-order component.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error you get has to do with the fact that `inputVal` becomes an array instead of string on `SET_INPUT` action dispatch. Fix your reducer as follows:

```js
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_INPUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                inputVal: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

You also have to connect `inputVal` to input value using `connect()` function:

```js
<input type="text" value={props.inputVal} {...} />
```